# Not show label for an empty property with LabelFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using MVC3 w/ Razor and I have a model that has quite a few properties that are sometimes empty.
Other than a custom htmlHelper, or using an if/then in the view for every LabelFor/DisplayFor pair, is there a way to not display the LabelFor/DisplayFor for a property that is empty or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.... You need the above mentioned solutions or additional view models.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I created my own helper: LabelAndDisplayFor that checks for null/empty and then chooses to display the field.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelAndDisplayFor<tModel, tValue>(this HtmlHelper<tModel> html, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<tModel, tValue>> field,
        bool hideIfEmpty = false) {

        if (hideIfEmpty) {
            var v = field.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
            if (v == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v.ToString())) {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.Append("<div class='display-line'>");
        result.Append("<div class='display-label'>");
        result.Append(html.LabelFor(field));
        result.Append("</div>");

        // ... etc ...
```